# iPhone Simulator Crash

Tags: iphone, object

I finished building a small app with audio, clicking "next" button will play a sound and take me to the next page, clicking "back" will play a sound and take me back to the previous page. But if I do the next, back twice, the simulator crashes and I receive the below message from the log. Anyone can help please, cheers.
 the message is: *** Thread1: Programme received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" *** 
while the code does compile well and I can turn the pages (41 in total).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is most always caused by trying to call a method on an object that has already been deallocated.  One way to diagnose this issue is to use the Zombies template in Instruments.  It will give you a dialog (with the call stack) when you message a deallocated object.  No matter what the exact cause, this is most certainly related to your memory management.

Comment: Thank you very much, how would I correct this please, what code do i need to write and where should i put the necessary code for that issue? cheers!

Comment: First, you have to find out where the problem is occurring.  This is what Instruments is for. I would recommend this resource: http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Comment: That is very nice of you! I'm having a look and will let you know if that resolved my issue. thanks again!

Comment: This has helped me, it's all sorted now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess.

You said that it crashes if you click next, then back twice.
I'm assuming that you keep the pages in an array, correct? If so, by clicking back twice you are trying to load a page with an index of -1. An array doesn't have an object at the index -1.

If I'm right, All you have to do is this:

```
// In the back button code:
if(currentPageIndex - 1 < 0) {
     // Dont go back
} else {
     // Go Back
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, dtuckernet was right, it was the memory management issue, all sorted now, thank you for your help.